# Set-ItemProperty working in PowerShell 5.1, but not in 7.0

Tags: powershell

I installed PowerShell 7.0 and started some testing. The following script works with no errors in PowerShell 5.1.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\TestSite" -Name physicalPath -Value "D:\Dev\Test\Website\WebSiteDown"
```

In PowerShell 7.0 I tried to change the import to use the updated "IISAdministration" module instead of the older "WebAdministration". I get the same error with both modules.

```
Set-ItemProperty: D:\Dev\OProTrunk\Website\WebSiteDown\OctopusCommand\Test.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\TestSite" -Name physicalPath -Value  …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.
```

Both were running as administrator to be able to update the web site physical path. Do I need to format the property different with PowerShell 7.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you will need to interact with your compatibility session for Windows PowerShell here.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$session = Get-PSSession -Name WinPSCompatSession
$sb = {Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\TestSite" -Name physicalPath -Value "D:\Dev\Test\Website\WebSiteDown"}
Invoke-Command -Scriptblock $sb -Session $session
```

The `IIS` PSDrive is created by the WebAdministration provider. Since that provider only loads in Windows PowerShell (at least on my system), you will need to access it there.

Comment: When I do this, the variable $session comes back as null. Am I missing having something installed?

Comment: In PowerShell 7.0, if you run `Import-Module WebAdministration`, you should get a message about incompatibility. That message will state what session name is created. That is what you need to use in your `Get-PSSession` command. If you have no other sessions at all, you can just use `$session = Get-PSSession`.

Comment: When I changed the line from
$session = Get-PSSession -Name WinPSCompat*
to
$session = Get-PSSession -Name WinPSCompatSession
it worked.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When setting the $sb value, if you want to use local variables inside (e.g. $sitename), you need to use $Using:sitename in its place.  It's ok, step back from the ledge.